# error in androidplot xml file

Tags: android, xml, androidplot

I'm implementing chart applications using Android Plot jar files examples.. It shows the application runs on the Jar file's `com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot`. But while i'm trying after configuring the project, it shows the error as,..

```
Could not find class 'com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot', referenced from method com.androidplot.xy.SimpleXYPlotActivity.onCreate
```

Help me find a solution...

My xml code is,..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<com.androidplot.xy.XYPlot
        android:id="@+id/mySimpleXYPlot"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="10px"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px"
        title="A Simple XYPlot Example"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually that means you either dont have the androidplot jar in your project's /libs dir, or if you are using an IDE like IntelliJ or Eclipse with ADT you havn't explicitly added the jar to your classpath.

Additionally, if you are using Androidplot 0.5.1 or later, you'll need to change this line:

```
title="A Simple XYPlot Example"
```

to

```
androidPlot.title="A Simple XYPlot Example"
```